# initializing 2d std::array in a class works in release build but not in debug

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a 2d Array class for different use cases where I know the size at compile time and that it won't change during runtime. IE setting up a grid for a battleships game.

current implementation works in both debug and release when using balanced 2d arrays such as 2 by 2, however when using unbalanced 2d arrays like 2 by 3 it will work in release but not in debug. I get expression: array subscript out of range when debugging

im using visual studio 2022 RC with std 20 enabled

header file

```
template <class T,unsigned int colSize,unsigned int rowSize>
  class TwoDArray{
  public:
  TwoDArray(){

    for (int i = 0; i < colSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = j;
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
         }
         std::cout <<  "   " << i << std::endl;
    }

 }
  private:
  std::array<std::array<T, colSize>, rowSize> matrix;

}
```

in main

```
int main(){  

   auto p = TwoDArray<int,2 ,3>{};
   
   return 0;
}
```

[releaseBuild for creating 2d array in class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To5J9.png) .png

[debugBuild for creating 2d array in class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzkcf.png)

Comment: You mixed up `colSize` and `rowSize` in your for loops. The outer one should be `rowSize`

Comment: The debug build is being helpful and adding additional checks that you aren't going out of bounds of the array, the release build lets you do whatever you want and you get "lucky" that it doesn't crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing up the `colSize` and `rowSize` in the `for` loops was the problem. Good to know about what the release build allows you to do.